# Get order of list by value

Tags: java, list, sorting

I have an order of list with different values:

```
List<Double> values = new LinkedList<Double>();
values.add(0.1);
values.add(0.8);
values.add(0.3);
```

What is the fastest way to get a list with indexes depending on the order of values of the given list, in this case {1, 3, 2} because 0.1 is the smallest, 0.2 the second smallest and 0.8 the third smallest?

Comment: What is the current _slow_ way you have in hand?

Comment: are you looking for sorting this list?

Comment: The current slow idea would be to look for the smallest index, then for the second smallest value, than for the third smallest value... But that would mean if a have for example 100 values that I have to go through the list 100 times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A way to get this index list, using only jdk5

```
    List<Float> positions = new ArrayList<Float>();
    List<Integer> indexes = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    positions.add(0.1f);
    positions.add(0.8f);
    positions.add(0.3f);

    // copy float elements to another List, so to keep the order
    List<Float> sortedPositions = new ArrayList<Float>();
    Collections.copy(sortedPositions, positions);
    Collections.sort(sortedPositions);

    for (Float position : positions) {
        indexes.add(sortedPositions.indexOf(position));
    }

    for (Integer index : indexes) {
        System.out.print(index + ",");
    }
    // prints 1,3,2,
```

Comment: Assumng the values are unique, otherwise this approach won't work. And this runs in O(n²) ;).

Comment: I cannot guarantee my values are unique, but if I have {0.1, 0.8, 0.3, 0.3} this would give me {1, 3, 2, 2}, which is okay for what I need.

Comment: @ZouZou collections sort runs in O(nlogn). The for loops runs in O(n) complexity. So the run is O(nlogn)

Comment: @VassilisB No, the for loop runs in O(n²) because indexOf runs in O(n)

Answer (score 1):

If all the values are uniques, one way is to use a `TreeMap` and then get back the corresponding indexes calling `values()`.

```
TreeMap<Double, Integer> map = new TreeMap<>();
int index = 0;
for(Double d : values){
    map.put(d, ++index);
}
System.out.println(map.values()); //[1, 3, 2]
```

This approach runs in `O(nlogn)` (but uses extra memory space).

If the values are not unique, you could use a `TreeMap<Double, List<Integer>>` and then flatmap the `Collection<List<Integer>>`

Answer (score -2):

You have to sort the list so that it will be sorted in the natural order before using is:

```
Collections.sort(values);
```

Comment: @ZouZou I thought he said get order of the list by value and not by index, right?

Comment: _"What is the fastest way to get a list with indexes depending on the order of values of the given list, in this case {1, 3, 2}"_